# How to properly access dictionary keys from dictionaries stored in list?

Tags: python

I am a complete beginner reading Crash Course Python by Eric Matthes. Here is my code trying to access a dictionary key, with the dictionaries stored within the list `shirts`.

```
red_shirt = {'shirt_color': 'red', 'shirt_price': 20}
blue_shirt = {'shirt_color': 'blue', 'shirt_price': 25}
green_shirt = {'shirt_color': 'green', 'shirt_price': 30}

shirts = [red_shirt, blue_shirt, green_shirt]

user_input = input('Which shirt would you like to purchase?\n:')
for shirt in shirts:
```

So far I believe I have an issue with the `for` loop... Should I be using a second `for` loop to access the keys within the dictionary?

```
    if shirt['shirt_color'] == 'red':
        #shirt_color = 'red'
        print('You bought the ' + shirt['shirt_color'] + ' shirt for $' + str(shirt['shirt_price']))
```

Opposed to using `k['v']` to access the values of the dictionary, I have also tried using `.format`.

```
    elif shirt['shirt_color'] == 'blue':
        #shirt_color = 'blue'
        print('You bought the ' + shirt['shirt_color'] + ' shirt for $' + str(shirt['shirt_price']))
    elif shirt['shirt_color'] == 'green':
        #shirt_color = 'green'
        print('You bought the ' + shirt['shirt_color'] + ' shirt for $' + str(shirt['shirt_price']))
    else:
        print('It seems we do not have the shirt you are looking for, please try again')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you almost got what you wanted, you just forgot that you needed to actually reference the user input you requested.

```
red_shirt = {'shirt_color': 'red', 'shirt_price': 20}
blue_shirt = {'shirt_color': 'blue', 'shirt_price': 25}
green_shirt = {'shirt_color': 'green', 'shirt_price': 30}

shirts = [red_shirt, blue_shirt, green_shirt]

user_input = input('Which shirt would you like to purchase?\n:')
for shirt in shirts:
    if shirt['shirt_color'] == user_input:
        print('You bought the ' + shirt['shirt_color'] + ' shirt for $' + str(shirt['shirt_price']))
```

Comment: Ah thank you, I was driving myself crazy wondering why the output would print all the values in the list. However, that makes a lot of sense now that the initial if statement for user input was not there.

Comment: While it might seem ridiculous to have had that problem after you see the answer, not only have I made similar mistakes myself when I was learning to program for the first time... over 30 years later, I *still* find that I sometimes make those sorts of mistakes.  The big difference between then and now is that  I now find them on my own.  People can reasonably keep about 5 to 9 things in their active thoughts at once.  To program without ever doing this sort of thing, you need to keep track of more than that. So either take notes about what you're doing or expect this sort of issue.